# Datatables csv download add custom columns to file

Tags: javascript, csv, datatable, datatables

I've been working with Datatables for a couple of days and I have this issue:
I have a method that downloads the data from a Datatable in a csv file, a table with three columns (Id, Type and Quantity):

```
_mVM.downloadCSV = function (item, event) {
        var table = $("#Table" + item.Id()).DataTable();
        var contentParts = [], rowParts = [], visibleColumns = [], column, data, field;
        var rows = table.rows({ filter: "applied" });
        var rowsData = rows.data();
        var columns = table.columns();
        var columnsCount = columns.data().length;
        //Columns and headers
        for (var i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            column = table.column(i);
            if (column.visible()) {
                visibleColumns.push(column.dataSrc());
                rowParts.push($(column.header()).html());
            }
        }
        if (rowParts.length > 0) {
            contentParts.push(rowParts.join(","));
        }
        // Rows
        for (var rowNum = 0; rowNum < rowsData.length; rowNum++) {
            rowParts = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < visibleColumns.length; j++) {
                field = visibleColumns[j];
                data = rowsData[rowNum][field];
                rowParts.push($(data).html());
            }
            contentParts.push(rowParts.join(","));
        }
        var test = contentParts.join("\n");

        var dltrData = test;
        var blob = new Blob([dltrData], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;" });
        saveAs(blob, item.selsite() + ".csv");
    }
```

The thing is that inside the file that will be downloaded I need to add (manually) another column, an empty one with the header 'Extra', at the end of the ones that are from the datatable (that one will be the fourth one). Can it be added using the same method (downloadCSV) or only the Datatable columns can get inside that file?

Comment: Where would the values from this fourth column come from?  Are they randomly generated?

Comment: @PatrickSteadman They don't come from anywhere. They are not in the datatable but I need to appear in the downloaded file. Let's say it's an extra hard-coded column, a empty one. The first three columns, they come from the datatable.

Comment: So... I have three columns from my datatable and the fourth one should be an extra one, with the header like "Extra" and with empty values in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach roughly like this might work, where extraHeader is the name of the column, and extraRowData is an array of the values of the column in the order of the rows.  You'd want to make this code more robust.

```
_mVM.downloadCSV = function (item, event, extraHeader, extraRowData) {
    var table = $("#Table" + item.Id()).DataTable();
    var contentParts = [], rowParts = [], visibleColumns = [], column, data, field;
    var rows = table.rows({ filter: "applied" });
    var rowsData = rows.data();
    var columns = table.columns();
    var columnsCount = columns.data().length;
    //Columns and headers
    for (var i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
        column = table.column(i);
        if (column.visible()) {
            visibleColumns.push(column.dataSrc());
            rowParts.push($(column.header()).html());
        }
    }
    if (extraHeader) rowParts.push(extraHeader);
    if (rowParts.length > 0) {
        contentParts.push(rowParts.join(","));
    }
    // Rows
    for (var rowNum = 0; rowNum < rowsData.length; rowNum++) {
        rowParts = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < visibleColumns.length; j++) {
            field = visibleColumns[j];
            data = rowsData[rowNum][field];
            rowParts.push($(data).html());
            if(extraRowData && rowNum < extraRowData.length) rowParts.push(extraRowData[rowNum]);
        }
        contentParts.push(rowParts.join(","));
    }
    var test = contentParts.join("\n");

    var dltrData = test;
    var blob = new Blob([dltrData], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;" });
    saveAs(blob, item.selsite() + ".csv");
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! :)